# OfficeR error: "Docx is already edited", but file doesn't even exist yet. What could be going on?

Tags: r, officer

I have a problem that would be difficult to replicate, thats why i just want ideas of what could be behind this error. When i create a docx an want to save it in the NAS in my office, i would get this error (where doc2 is the docx and Direc4 is my direction):

> Error in print.rdocx(doc2, target = Direc4) :
> H:\DpProMon\DPM\Programa Monetario Diario\2021\Actas\23 Ago Informe
> comité monetario y cambiario.docx is already edited. You must close
> the document in order to be able to write the file.

Nevertheless, the File dont exist yet. what could be going on?
Sometimes when im triying to save an actual Word using office, i could get an error that someone else is editing the file (while thats not actually true), and that error would dissapear after a couple seconds. But in R this error doesnt stops. Some help?

Comment: I just had the same issue. I noticed that I had was a residual temporal Word file (something like "~.docx", like the one that Office creates when editing a file in Word); by deleting that file it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I couldn't find the temp file. I deleted cache, temp files from word and local, hidden files in my folder..etc. Could be because in my case I'm using GitHub desktop and also Dropbox so maybe that adds more temp files. The only solution was to change the name of the printed file each time you want to save it. Silly but works.